# How to separate tables contained in an excel file in different CSV?

Tags: ruby, linux, excel, bash, csv

I have an excel with multiple tables separated by blank rows and I want to save each table in separate CSV files with a script. How could I do it?

Thanks for the help

**UPDATE:**

INPUT EXAMPLE:
[Excel Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Hnfd.png)

OUTPUT EXAMPLE:

I want everyone of those columns in a file like this one.

```
276.1722 54.318 50.6335
276.373 52.573 51.4047
277.0097 50.864 51.9912
277.9329 49.4127 52.8294
279.0832 47.9623 53.3041
280.3554 46.5477 53.5295
281.3679 44.9695 53.8862
282.4689 43.4235 54.1254
283.4763 41.8019 54.0885
284.5859 40.3595 53.5828
285.7263 38.941 52.988
286.8929 37.5684 52.3438
288.0729 36.2914 51.5373
289.0561 35.1335 50.4119
289.7246 34.2113 48.8901
290.0624 33.3207 47.2446
290.1395 32.2516 45.6541
290.0895 31.2818 44.0091
289.7804 30.5224 42.2812
289.211 29.8383 40.5862
```

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: I add an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternate way of storing the data:
You could actually store them in an excel file and in different sheets and use these gems depending on if your working with old or new excel: 
'Roo', 'roo-xls', 'spreadsheet', 'write_xlsx'

Loop through the sheets and perform the same logic instead of placing them throughout a single sheet.